# Calling CreditsCallback.php when order reached status refunded by calling graph API

Tags: callback, status, facebook-credits, credits

I would like to ask: does FB call creditsCallback.php with status refunded, when we update order status to refunded through FB graph API? Because we want to handle this status also, but our creditsCallback.php is not called, when order reached this status. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing as I implement our refunding system.

I have made some tests and I can confirm to you that Facebook DOES NOT call you back notifying the refunded status.

So, when you make the POST call to the graph API saying that you want to refund the order, you should verify that the response from facebook is simply "true" and then update your database.